# How to get Gallery Directory with python for kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I start my first kivy project so it may be dump question. Has python similar code like this ?

> final String path = android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;

Or I have to iterate directories to find gallery?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [pyjnius](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius#pyjnius) module to call Java code from Python. In your case:

```
from jnius import autoclass
res = str(autoclass('android.os.Environment').DIRECTORY_DCIM)
```

I didn't check code.